# Parsing of IN-Clause in JPQL typedquery

Tags: jpql, openjpa

I am trying execute query which were working fine in JPA but these are not working on Open JPA, have you any idea?

```
String iNString;
try {
            String query = "Delete FROM  Table1o WHERE o.Pk1 IN('"+ iNString+ "') and o.countryCode = '"+ countryCode+ "'";
            entityManager().createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
            LOGGER.info("Delete Query-----------------: " + query);

        } 
catch( Exception exception ) {
            throw new DataLayerException(exception.getMessage(),exception);
        }
```

> Error:-org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No
>   metadata was found for type "class java.lang.String". The class is not
>   enhanced.; nested exception is  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: No
>   metadata was found for type "class java.lang.String". The class is not
>   enhanced.

Comment: o.Pk1 is a RAW field in table.

Answer (score -1):

EntityManager em = Relationship.entityManager();
        StringBuilder sbQueryString = new StringBuilder("SELECT o FROM table AS o WHERE 1 = 1");
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(DTO.getNameEng())) {
            sbQueryString.append(" AND LOWER (o.NameEng) LIKE :_NAME_ENG");
        }

```
    sbQueryString.append(" order by o.relationshipNameEng");
    TypedQuery<Relationship> q = em.createQuery(sbQueryString.toString(), User.class);
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(DTO.getRelationshipNameEng())) {
        q.setParameter("_NAME_ENG", "%" + DTO.getNameEng().toLowerCase() + "%");
    }
```